# CGContextClip - Fill intersection

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am trying out a simple fill, two intersecting circles with same radius and to fill the intersection alone.Below is what I tried

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);

   // Draw first circle    
    CGContextAddArc(context, 150, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // Draw second circle
    CGContextAddArc(context, 200, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
    CGContextEOClip(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

}
```

My code doesn't even render second circle in context. I have gone through lot of question related to CGContextClip here in forum but most of them uses CGPath in their sample. Only CGpaths can be clipped? Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `CGContextStrokePath()`, `CGContextEOClip()` and `CGContextFillPath()`
all clear the current path. Therefore the final `CGContextFillPath()` has no path to fill.

The following code should now work to draw the intersection of the circles:

```
// Use first circle as clipping path:
CGContextAddArc(context, 150, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextClip(context);
// Draw second circle:
CGContextAddArc(context, 200, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

---

*Update:* The following code fills and strokes the intersection:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddArc(context, 150, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextAddArc(context, 200, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
CGContextAddArc(context, 200, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextAddArc(context, 150, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

---

(Original code which does not work:)

To fill and stroke a path, use `CGContextDrawPath()`:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);

CGContextAddArc(context, 150, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextAddArc(context, 200, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathEOFillStroke);
```

Comment: Thanks.I have tried your code and it displays the second circle now but the fill is done on part of the circles which are not intersected and intersection is left blank. I want it other way, i.e, I want the fill only to be done in circle intersection.

Comment: @slysid: Then call `CGContextAddArc(..., 0)`, i.e. set the clockwise parameter to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Still the same. Tried as                              CGContextAddArc(context, 150, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, 200, 150, 50, 0, 2 * M_PI, 0);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathEOFillStroke);                                    I even tried with CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke) - winding rule but this time everything is filled with the circles.

Comment: @slysid: OK, I see the problem now. Is the yellow border important, or do you need only the red filled area of the intersection?

Comment: red filled area is what I am looking for now but would appreciate if you could elaborate the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @slysid: My first approach using eofill does not work. I have updated the answer with new code that draws the intersection of the two circles.

Comment: It worked.Thank you.I will accept your answer.If you have time, what should I do to have the intersection fill along with the stroke.

Comment: @slysid: I have updated the answer. There might be a simpler solution, but that is what I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this

```
- (UIImage *)colorImage:(UIImage *)origImage withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(origImage.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, (CGRect){ {0,0}, origImage.size} );

CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, origImage.size.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){ pt, origImage.size }, [origImage CGImage]);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

and you can also try [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)